# Python Plotly hoverover information for two or more heatmaps

Tags: python, hover, plotly, label, heatmap

I am plotting 3 heatmaps in plotly on top of each other and would like to display the z value of all 3 when I hover over the (x,y) points.

I have seen that for scatter plots you can use unified x to display the info of all plots on hover. Is there a similar way to do a unified z for heatmap plots?

I have also seen that you can create a data frame of custom texts and use those as hoverlabels but that seems a little too excessive for what I'm trying to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- this is effectively the answer [Plotly Python - Heatmap - Change Hovertext (x,y,z)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569092/plotly-python-heatmap-change-hovertext-x-y-z)
- simulated 3 heat maps on top of each other
- build text array which are the z values across all three layers

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

dfs = [pd.DataFrame(index=list("abcd"), columns=list("ab"),
                    data=np.where(np.random.randint(1, 8, [4, 2]) == 1,
                                  np.nan, np.random.randint(1, 500, [4, 2]),)
                   )
       for i in range(3)]

# create text array same shape as z
text = pd.concat(dfs).groupby(level=0).agg({c:lambda v: ", ".join(v.astype(str)) for c in dfs[0].columns}).values

# figure
go.Figure([go.Heatmap(z=df.values, x=df.columns, y=df.index, name=i, text=text, hoverinfo="text")
    for i, df in enumerate(dfs)
])
```