# Plotly Python - Heatmap - Include and update additional label parameters in Hovertext when using slider

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, heatmap

I want to plot data in a heatmap in Plotly and include a slider to toggle between different categories of a certain slider column.

I am currently able to update the text in the `hovertemplate`, but I would also like to include additional information in the box, which should also be updated whenever the slider is changed.

As an example,

```
# create Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_label': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 'y_label': [3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5], 'z_label':[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
                   'A': [10, 11, 12,13,14,15,16,17,18], 'B': [10, 12, 14,16,18,20,22,24,26], 'C': [12, 14, 16,18,20,22,24,26,28],
                   'slider':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']})


# create list of dataframes where each dataframe is a filtered dataframe based on the selected slider category
multi_dfs = [df[df['slider'] == s] for s in df['slider'].unique()]


# create and name each frame in the heatmap based on the slider name
frames = [
    go.Frame(data=go.Heatmap(z=df['z_label'],
                             x=df['x_label'],
                             y=df['y_label']),
             name=df['slider'].iloc[0],
            )
    for i, df in enumerate(multi_dfs)
]

# plot the heatmap figure
fig = go.Figure(data=frames[0].data, frames=frames).update_layout(

    # iterate over frames to generate slider steps
    sliders=[{"active":1, "currentvalue":{"prefix": "slider: "},
              "steps": [{"args": [[f.name],{"frame": {"duration": 0, "redraw": True},
                                            "mode": "immediate",},],
                         "label": f.name, "method": "animate",}
                        for f in frames],}]
)
# update hovertemplate labels and information
fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="X Custom Label: %{x}"
                "<br>Y Custom Label: %{y}"
                "<br>Z Custom Label: %{z}<extra></extra>"
                      )
```

I get the following heatmap

[image]

I would like to add to the hover information box the data that are in columns `A`, `B`, and `C`.

I am not sure how to pass and update these parameters when the plot has a slider.

Comment: I would find it difficult to update with slider values, as a template is just that, a template.

Comment: i am not sure if this is possible with plotly alone, but since you put down `plotly-dash` as a tag, would you consider a plotly-dash solution?

Comment: I would, my implementation is in dash actually, but also wasn’t so sure on how to do it with dash

Comment: @finstats so you want changing the slider to add additional information to the hovertemplate? what information specifically?

Comment: I want the information of columns A, B, and C to also be included in the hover template, and when the slider is changed, that information should be updated for all cells as it is updated for X Custom Label, Y Custom Label, and  Z Custom Label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that when you pass slider information to the `sliders` argument in the `fig.update_layout` method, there isn't an easy way to retrieve the value of the slider when it is being used live. This means that even with a callback where we pass the figure as an input, we don't have an easy way of updating the `hovertemplate` because the state of the slider isn't known as you're using it.

We can get around this by using instead using `dcc.Slider` to render the slider – this will be separate from the figure so we don't run into the issue of having to retrieve the slider value from within the plotly figure.

However, from [the documentation](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/slider), I believe that dcc.Slider only allows numerical values – so when we define the slider, we need to provide numerical values like `0, 1, 2,...` and create a dictionary to map them to your categories `'a', 'b', 'c',...,`. Then when we use the callback to retrieve the slider values, we use the same dictionary so that we know which category on the slider was selected (similar to the example [here](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/slider#non-linear-slider-and-updatemode)). Then in the callback, we can update both the data in the figure and the hovertemplate accordingly.

To get multiple columns of data into the hovertemplate, you'll want to pass multiple columns of your df to the customdata parameter as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278586/5327068).

I know this is out of the scope of your question, but I noticed that the scale of the heatmap changes every time you toggle the slider because the input data changes – whether data in the heatmap spans values from 10-12 or 20-22, the colors will remain unchanged. So I added `zmin` and `zmax` arguments to `go.Heatmap` based on the global min and max of values in your data, but if this isn't what you want, feel free to drop these arguments.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import dash
from dash import Input, Output, State, ctx, dcc, html
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

# create Pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'x_label': [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 'y_label': [3,4,5,3,4,5,3,4,5], 'z_label':[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
                   'A': [10, 11, 12,13,14,15,16,17,18], 'B': [10, 12, 14,16,18,20,22,24,26], 'C': [12, 14, 16,18,20,22,24,26,28],
                   'slider':['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','c']})


# create dictionary mapping slider category to dataframe filtered by slider category
slider_df_dict = {
    slider_value:df_group for 
    slider_value, df_group in df.groupby("slider")
}

zmin, zmax = min(df['z_label']), max(df['z_label'])
customdata = np.stack((df['A'], df['B'], df['C']), axis=-1)
slider_values = list(slider_df_dict.keys())

# create and name each frame in the heatmap based on the slider name
frames = [
    go.Frame(data=go.Heatmap(
            z=df['z_label'],
            x=df['x_label'],
            y=df['y_label'],
            customdata=customdata,
            zmin=zmin,
            zmax=zmax
        ),
        name=slider_name,
    )
    for slider_name, df in slider_df_dict.items()
]

# plot the heatmap figure
fig = go.Figure(data=frames[0].data, frames=frames)

# update hovertemplate labels and information
fig.update_traces(
        hovertemplate="X Custom Label: %{x}"
                    "<br>Y Custom Label: %{y}"
                    "<br>Z Custom Label: %{z}"
                    "<br>Col A: %{customdata[0]}"
                    "<br>Col B: %{customdata[1]}"
                    "<br>Col C: %{customdata[2]}"
                    "<extra></extra>"
    )

app = dash.Dash()

## if i am not mistaken, categorical dash slider has not been implemented yet
## so we still need to pass numbers and then display the marks as categories
slider_value_to_mark_dict = {i:s for i,s in enumerate(slider_values)}

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(figure=fig, id="fig-heatmap"),
    dcc.Slider(
        min=0, 
        max=len(slider_values)-1, 
        step=1, 
        marks=slider_value_to_mark_dict, id="slider") 
])

@app.callback(
    Output("fig-heatmap", "figure"),
    Input("slider", "value"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_fig(slider_value):
    slider_mark = slider_value_to_mark_dict[slider_value]
    slider_df = slider_df_dict[slider_mark]
    customdata = np.stack((slider_df['A'], slider_df['B'], slider_df['C']), axis=-1)
    frames = [
        go.Frame(
            data=go.Heatmap(
                z=slider_df['z_label'],
                x=slider_df['x_label'],
                y=slider_df['y_label'],
                customdata=customdata,
                zmin=zmin,
                zmax=zmax
                ),
            name=slider_mark,
        )
    ]
    fig = go.Figure(data=frames[0].data, frames=frames)
    fig.update_traces(
        hovertemplate="X Custom Label: %{x}"
                    "<br>Y Custom Label: %{y}"
                    "<br>Z Custom Label: %{z}"
                    "<br>Col A: %{customdata[0]}"
                    "<br>Col B: %{customdata[1]}"
                    "<br>Col C: %{customdata[2]}"
                    "<extra></extra>"
    )
    return fig

app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome – glad to hear my answer was helpful!